# JavaScript anonymous function expression vs IIFE

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, iife, function-expression

Encountered some code that's using IIFEs in an expression rather than just a normal function.

```
var custom_type = (function() {
    return $('#myDiv').attr('custom_type');
})();
```

Normally I would write this as something like:

```
var custom_type = function() {
    return $('#myDiv').attr('custom_type');
};
```

What's the reason for the IIFE?  The only thing I can think of is that the IIFE might assign the `custom_type` variable only once at the beginning whereas the second might continue to check for the updated type every time the variable is referenced.

Comment: The first one executes the function and store its result, the seconds stores function as definition.

Comment: The first one is equivalent to `var custom_type = $('#myDiv').attr('custom_type')`. So both examples have different results (in the first one, `custom_type` is a string, and in the second one it's a function) and without context it's impossible to tell why the first one was used. Presumably whoever wrote the code didn't want `custom_type` to be a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this example, you can dispense with the function altogether and just do:

```
var custom_type = $('#myDiv').attr('custom_type');
```

However in general you can use an IIFE for more complex "just-in-time" computation of variable assignments - I like to use them if I need to iterate over something, so I can have `i` without polluting the current scope.

In your second example, though, the result is completely different - you will need to *call* the function `custom_type()` to get the *current* value, whereas the first piece of code will get its value once, and the variable will hold that value.

Comment: I guess that was the better question, why the IIFE instead of assigning it to the `.attr` return value directly.  Seems needlessly complex.

Answer (score 3):

The IIFE will actually run (immediately-invoked function expression), so the variable will be set to its response.

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate this, watch your JS console for the output: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4JmT/1/

Code Here:

```
var custom_type = (function() {
    return 'foo';
})();

var custom_type2 = function() {
    return 'bar';
};

console.log('iife = ' + custom_type);
console.log('non-iife = ' + custom_type2);
```

In your JS console you'll see something similar to:

```
iife = foo
```

and

```
non-iife = function () {
    return 'bar';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one of yours (IIFE) executes the function and store its result, the seconds stores function as definition.

```
(function(x) {
    return x * 2;
})(5);
```

You are making a call like to normal funciton: func(arg1, arg2), but instead of function name you pass whole function definition, so the above would return *10* like:

```
function multiply(x) {
    return x * 2;
}

multiply(5);
```

They mean the same thing, you are making calls. Unlikely the first, second is definition plus a call.

Answer (score 1):

IIFEs allow you to invoke a function (anonymous or otherwise) at the point of creation.
Have you looked at this?
http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/